# Why cannot add the whole Object to an array with using push method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to create an Array of Objects and don´t know why arr.push(obj) doesn´t work in this case?

```js
let DAYS = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
let obj = {
  "name": "",
  "id": 0,
  "sub": ""
};
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < DAYS.length; i++) {
  obj.name = DAYS[i];
  obj.id = i + 1;
  obj.sub = "Today is " + DAYS[i];
  arr.push({
    "name": obj.name,
    "id": obj.id,
    "sub": obj.sub
  });
  //arr.push(obj); <===== why this one doesn´t work???
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: what do u mean does not work. btw is it because there is syntax error after Sunday on first line

Comment: It certainly does work. What is probably confusing you is that you constantly change the *same* `obj` and add the same obj to the array multiple times.

Comment: Put `let obj = ...;` inside the loop, then it will do what you want.

Comment: @cmgchess That backslash is almost certainly not in the actual code. The editor used in the new question wizard mistakenly escapes characters.

Comment: Yes it works! I was placing the Object in a wrong place! Must be in the loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of `obj` every time in the loop instead of reassigning the same `obj` every time.

For example:

```js
const DAYS = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < DAYS.length; i++) {
  const obj = {
    name: DAYS[i],
    id: i + 1,
    sub: "Today is " + DAYS[i]
  };
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

There is an option to optimize this whole loop a bit by using `map` function, for example:

```js
const days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const arr = days.map((day, i) => ({
  name: day,
  id: i + 1,
  sub: `Today is ${day}`
}));
console.log(arr);
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, a perfect optimization. Thanks!

Comment: @BergMonika No worries! Don't you mind upvoting my answer and selecting it as a solution if it is helpful for you? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot vote as I am a new member but I selected it as the solution... Still not much experience here.